# How to improve accuracy of NIntegrate over ImplicitRegion

Tags: numerical-integration, regions

I'm trying to compute the area of a implicit region given as

```
R = ImplicitRegion[
       0 < Sinh[u]/Cosh[v] < 1 && 0 < Sinh[v]/Cosh[u] < 1,
       {{u, 0, Infinity}, {v, 0, Infinity}}
    ]
```

The region looks like this:

```
RegionPlot[
  0 < Sinh[u]/Cosh[v] < 1 && 0 < Sinh[v]/Cosh[u] < 1, 
  {u, 0, 2}, {v, 0, 2}
]
```

[image: Implicit region]

I used `NIntegrate` (Mathematica 10.4) like this:

```
NIntegrate[1, Element[{u, v}, R]]
(* Out: 0.884886 *)
```

However I happen to know that the correct answer should be $\pi^2/8 = 1.2337$.

I'm reading the documentation for `NIntegrate`, but I'm quite overwhelmed by the amount of possible options. How can I improve the result of `NIntegrate` in this case?

Answer (score 10):

You can first discretize the region as follows:

```
reg = DiscretizeRegion[
         ImplicitRegion[0 < Sinh[u]/Cosh[v] < 1 && 0 < Sinh[v]/Cosh[u] < 1,
                        {{u, 0, 3}, {v, 0, 3}}]];
```

Now `NIntegrate` gives us better values:

```
NIntegrate[1, Element[{u, v}, reg]]
```

> 1.23371

I don't know why putting `Infinity` as the limits give terrible results.

Comment: The result gets even better when I don't use `MaxCellMeasure` (1.23356). But strangely it get's worse again when I increase the bounds from 3 to 4 (1.24179) or even higher.

Comment: @asmaier. That's interesting. Clearly a bug somewhere. I'll include that observation.

Answer (score 6):

Some of what is going on is that the region is numericized to the extent that the precision of the numbers in `R` is set to `7.`.  Then `NIintegrate` discretizes the region with

```
dR = DiscretizeRegion[
 ImplicitRegion[
  0 < Sech[v] Sinh[u] < 1.000000 && 0 < Sech[u] Sinh[v] < 1.000000 && 
   u >= 0 && v >= 0, {u, v}], PrecisionGoal -> 7., 
 AccuracyGoal -> ∞]
```

The difficulty arises with computing the region bounds:

```
RegionBounds@
 ImplicitRegion[
  0 < Sech[v] Sinh[u] < 1.`7. && 0 < Sech[u] Sinh[v] < 1.`7. && 
   u >= 0 && v >= 0, {u, v}]
(*  {{0, 0.9896590}, {0.00001562203, 0.9594784}}  *)
```

Well, there would be a problem in computing the bounds, since the region is infinite, but it's not clear why these numbers are found.  In any case, it is the region that is integrated over:

```
NIntegrate[1, Element[{u, v}, dR]]
Area@dR
(* 
  0.884886
  0.884886
*)
```

One can do better by truncating at explicit bounds, like @RunnyKine does:

```
dR2 = DiscretizeRegion[
  ImplicitRegion[
   0 < Sech[v] Sinh[u] < 1.`7. && 0 < Sech[u] Sinh[v] < 1.`7. && 
    u >= 0 && v >= 0, {u, v}],
  {{0, 6}, {0, 6}},
  PrecisionGoal -> 7.`, AccuracyGoal -> ∞]
NIntegrate[1, Element[{u, v}, dR2]]
(*  1.23365  *)
```

In general, I would say that discretizing the region introduces errors at the boundary that can have a significant impact. (It's basically a trapezoidal-rule approximation.)  One might consider a change of variables, if a suitable one can be found, to a region with finite bounds.  One can also revert to the old-style way of dealing with integrating over a region, [`Boole`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Boole.html):

```
NIntegrate[
 Boole[0 < Sech[v] Sinh[u] < 1 && 0 < Sech[u] Sinh[v] < 1 && u >= 0 &&
    v >= 0], {u, 0, Infinity}, {v, 0, Infinity}]
(*  1.2337  *)
```

Note that this does not work as well:

```
NIntegrate[Boole[RegionMember[R, {u, v}]], {u, 0, Infinity}, {v, 0, Infinity}]
```

> NIntegrate::slwcon: Numerical integration converging too slowly...
>
> NIntegrate::eincr: The global error of the strategy GlobalAdaptive has increased...

```
(*  1.07879  *)
```

It seems to have something to do with the `(u | v) ∈ Reals` added by `RegionMember`:

```
RegionMember[R, {u, v}]
(*
  (u | v) ∈ Reals && 0 < Sech[v] Sinh[u] < 1 && 
   0 < Sech[u] Sinh[v] < 1 && u >= 0 && v >= 0
*)
```

It must throw off `NIntegrate`'s symbolic preprocessor.