# Improve accuracy of NIntegrate with GlobalAdaptive over ImplicitRegion?

Tags: numerical-integration

Let's say that I want to integrate some arbitrarily "nice" function (uniformly $C^{\infty}$-smooth, for example) over an ImplicitRegion in more than three dimensions. For example, let's consider the integral $\int_{D\times D} 1\,\mathrm{d}\mu$, where $D$ is the unit disk in two dimensions. We can approximate this in Mathematica as follows:

```
disk2 = ImplicitRegion[x1^2 + y1^2 <= 1 && x2^2 + y2^2 <= 1, {x1, y1, x2, y2}]
val[n_] := NIntegrate[1, Element[{x1, y1, x2, y2}, disk2], WorkingPrecision -> n]
```

The exact value of this is $\pi^2$, but the numerical value returned by Mathematica 11.1 doesn't converge to $\pi^2$ for increasing $n$. Namely, val[50]-Pi^2 and val[100]-Pi^2 both give me the same numerical error, which is roughly $1.38\times 10^{-18}$. With slightly more complicated functions (that are still $C^1$ almost everywhere, at least), the error we get can be much worse; consider the following integral:

```
NIntegrate[Sqrt[(x1 - x2)^2 + (y1 - y2)^2], Element[{x1, y1, x2, y2}, disk2], WorkingPrecision -> n]
```

We should expect this integral to have a value of $\frac{128\pi}{45}$, but the output differs from that value by a little more than $4\times 10^{-5}$, regardless of the setting for WorkingPrecision. Additionally, it doesn't seem that DiscretizeRegion can really be applied to regions that can't be expressed as the product of $n$-dimensional regions for $n\leq 3$, which in the case of a more general region rules out the strategy [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/112840/how-to-improve-accuracy-of-nintegrate-over-implicitregion). Are there any general strategies I can use to get with arbitrary precision and accuracy the values of numerical integrals of $C^1$ functions on ImplicitRegions in more than three dimensions? Thanks for your time.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how long does it take to evaluate `val[50]` and `val[100]` for you? It seems to last forever for me...

Comment: I get an `NIntegrate::eincr` error, which stops the integration with the error you report, `1.38*^-18`. Don't you? If not, what version are you using? If so, why not report such information in the question?

Comment: I don't get an error at all. The computation completes perfectly for me. Also, I'm using Mathematica 11.1, as I mentioned.

Comment: That is to say, Mathematica doesn't complain at all. There is a slight _numerical_ error, which is what my issue is.

Comment: Sorry about overlooking the version.  I get this (V11.1.1): http://i.stack.imgur.com/dnIrW.png  It suggests a way to improve the result.  But if you get no error, then it won't help.

Comment: Interesting. I'll upgrade to 11.1.1 and see whether I can get better results by upping MaxErrorIncreases. Thanks!